# Geth syncing, how to keep on par with the network in syncronized blocks

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, fast-sync

I am trying to get data from the last block via my own local node. I do this by calling the RPC API on my node.
the issue I have is that the node is not fully synchronized and is never fully synchronized, it always lags behind the main net. and my use case is to try and get the latest transactions from the latest block.
I understand that `--fast` sync, which I am running right now, is not as synchronization-centric as the sync mode. But I want to know if there is a way to fully synchronize with the network.

that is probably possible since I can get the latest block data from an RPC provider on the internet but that happens to be limited in the request number.

Comment: Does your node have an SSD? HDDs aren't fast enough to keep up with synchronisation.

Comment: yes, I am running a VPS with a 300MB write speed.